# Magento how to include zend mail library in external php file

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework, magento-1.9

I have created a seperate php file in var directory which i used for cron jobs. I have added zend mail function buts its not working nor giving any error.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

    require_once('app/Mage.php'); //Path to Magento
    require_once('lib/Zend/Mail.php');
    require_once('lib/Zend/Mail/Transport/Smtp.php'); 
    umask(0);
    Mage::app();

        $mail = new Zend_Mail();
                     $mail->addTo('mymail@mail.com','apple');
                    $mail->setFrom('sender@mail.com','sender');
                  $mail->setSubject('notifications');
                    $mail->setBodyHTML('<p>hi</p>','UTF-8');  // your content or message

                try {
                    $mail->send();
                    echo "mail sent";

                }
                catch (Exception $e) {
                    print_r($e);

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume your var directory is in public, 
add autoload path

```
require getcwd() . '/../vendor/autoload.php'; // configure autoload path as per your file location.

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require_once('app/Mage.php'); //Path to Magento, may be this not required.  
umask(0);
Mage::app();

    $mail = new Zend_Mail();
                 $mail->addTo('mymail@mail.com','apple');
                $mail->setFrom('sender@mail.com','sender');
              $mail->setSubject('notifications');
                $mail->setBodyHTML('<p>hi</p>','UTF-8');  // your content or message

            try {
                $mail->send();
                echo "mail sent";

            }
            catch (Exception $e) {
                print_r($e);

            }
```